# How can I determine the best place to add indexes in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've tried doing some searching, but I am having a bit of trouble getting a grasp on this.

Once I explain a query, how can I look at the information and determine the best place to add an index to speed up the query.

For example I have this query:

```
    SELECT a.app_id, DATE_FORMAT(app_datetime, '%c/%d/%y %H:%i') as app_datetime, app_language
        , if((select count(w.app_id) from li_app_cnc as w where w.app_id = a.app_id) > 0 ,         concat('CNC: ',(select cnc_note from li_app_cnc as w where w.app_id = a.app_id)), 
            if((select count(x.app_id) from li_app_dnc as x where x.app_id = a.app_id) > 0, concat('DNC: ', (select cancel_note from li_app_dnc as x where x.app_id = a.app_id)), 
                if((select count(y.app_id) from li_app_canceled as y where y.app_id = a.app_id) > 0, concat('Canceled: ', (select cancel_note from li_app_canceled as y where y.app_id = a.app_id)),
                    concat(h.emp_firstname, ' ', h.emp_lastname)))) as int_id, app_notes, app_facility, app_department
        , app_requesting_person, app_service_provider
        , cast(AES_DECRYPT(les_name, '$privatekey') as char) as les_name
        , les_dob, cast(AES_DECRYPT(les_medicaid_id, '$privatekey') as char) as les_medicaid_id
        , billing_total_time, billing_workorder_received, billing_admin_fee
        , billing_notes, created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on, wo_entered_by
        , t.cancel_code, t.cancel_note
        , u.cnc_code, u.cnc_note
        , v.cancel_code as dnc_code, v.cancel_note as dnc_note
        FROM li_appointments.li_appointments as a
        left Join orangehrm_li.hs_hr_employee as h on a.terp_id = h.employee_id
        left Join li_appointments.li_app_canceled as t on t.app_id = a.app_id
        left Join li_appointments.li_app_cnc as u on u.app_id = a.app_id
        left Join li_appointments.li_app_dnc as v on v.app_id = a.app_id
        where (app_client_id in (select account_number from li_appointments.li_client_access 
            where id = $userid) or created_by = '$username') 
            and date(app_datetime) = date(now())
            and a.app_id  not in (select f.app_id from li_app_dnc as f)
```

Which takes about 14 secconds

It is explained as:

```
   1    PRIMARY                 a   ALL                 37539   Using where
   1    PRIMARY                 h   ALL                 1036    
   1    PRIMARY                 t   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   1    PRIMARY                 u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   1    PRIMARY                 v   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   9    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  f   unique_subquery PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1   Using index
   8    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  li_client_access    ALL                        72   Using where
   7    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  y   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   6    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  y   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   Using index
   5    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  x   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   4    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  x   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   Using index
   3    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  w   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   
   2    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  w   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   li_appointments.a.app_id    1   Using index
```

Comment: I put index on all fields appearing in a `WHERE`, `ON`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause. Subquestion: Is this a good approach?

Comment: @DanFromGermany That's a good start, but check the cardinality of the column as well. If your column is called `thing_type_id` and it has values `1, 2, 3, or 4`, then an index does not do a whole lot of good if there are only four different values in the entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thumb rules:

1. Index all the fields on which you will define `WHERE` conditions.
2. Index all the fields on which you will define relationships.
3. Index all the fields on which you will define grouping criteria.
4. Avoid indexing everything in your table. Think before creating the indexes.

(Although it depends on your specific needs, I personally avoid creating indexes on floating point columns)

Obviously, the above rules imply that you must index **all the fields** that work as primary key or as foreign key (if your tables are normalized, you already must have created the appropriate primary keys; if your tables are not normalized, then **normalize them**).

Comment: Thank you! Adding the correct indexes dropped this query from 20 seconds on average to .01 seconds.  My end users are eternal grateful.